# How do I use pageToken?

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a simple program, and this is my very first time using the Youtube API. I want to get all of the comments from any video, but I can't do it without "pageToken," someone told me. I can't seem to get what it does, or how to use it. I am using node.js v13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Top-Level Comments and Associated Replies

According to the official docs, there are two API endpoints at one's disposal w.r.t. reading the comments attached to any given video -- identified by its ID:

1. [`CommentThreads.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) and
2. [`Comments.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list).

The comments of any given video are structured such that the first endpoint above returns a *paginated set* of [top-level comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#resource) (i.e. `CommentThreads` resource) when invoked with parameter [`videoId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId) set as `videoId=VIDEO_ID`, where `VIDEO_ID` is the ID of the video of your interest.

The second API endpoint above is to be used for obtaining the *paginated* set of all [comment replies](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments#resource) (i.e. `Comments` resource) attached to any given top-level comment, by specifying to its parameter [`parentId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#parentId) the ID of the respective top-level comment.

Note that, even if the `CommentThreads` resource contains a list of comment replies within its property [`replies`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#replies), according to the docs, that list *is incomplete*. That is the reason why one need using the `CommentThreads.list` endpoint in tandem with `Comments.list` endpoint.

### The property `nextPageToken` and the parameter `pageToken`

Now, as mentioned above, the API returns sets of `CommentThreads` and, respectively, `Comments` resources. These sets are paginated, since each API call will return (by design) no more that 50 such items.

Consequently, for one to fetch all `CommentThreads` resources of a given video through `CommentThreads.list` API endpoint, will have to implement [pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination). The same is true w.r.t. the `Comments.list` API endpoint when it comes to fetch all `Comments` resources of any given top-level comment.

The meaning of pagination is simply the following: for to obtain the `n`-th page of a paginated result set, where `n >= 2`, one has to extract the value of the property `nextPageToken` from the `n-1`-th page as, say, `PAGE_TOKEN`, and pass on that value to the `n`-th API invoking URL to the parameter `pageToken` as `pageToken=PAGE_TOKEN`. If a given page does not contain the property `nextPageToken`, then the pagination reached its end.

### API Limitations Imposed by Design

According to [official Google staff statements](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134912604#comment3), the number of items obtained by paginating the result sets of `CommentThreads.list` endpoint is limited.

That limit is not specified, thus one needs to take into account, that, in cases, it will not be possible to obtain *all* top-level comments of a given video. This is unfortunate, but a fact.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this document: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs
It will answer all your questions.