# YouTube Data API to crawl all comments and replies

Tags: python, dataframe, youtube, web-crawler, youtube-data-api

I have been desperately seeking a solution to crawl all comments and corresponding replies for my research. Am having a very hard time creating a data frame that includes comment data in correct and corresponding orders.

I am gonna share my code here so you professionals can take a look and give me some insights.

```
def get_video_comments(service, **kwargs):
    comments = []
    results = service.commentThreads().list(**kwargs).execute()

    while results:
        for item in results['items']:
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']
            comment2 = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['publishedAt']
            comment3 = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorDisplayName']
            comment4 = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['likeCount']
            if 'replies' in item.keys():
                for reply in item['replies']['comments']:
                    rauthor = reply['snippet']['authorDisplayName']
                    rtext = reply['snippet']['textDisplay']
                    rtime = reply['snippet']['publishedAt']
                    rlike = reply['snippet']['likeCount']
                    data = {'Reply ID': [rauthor], 'Reply Time': [rtime], 'Reply Comments': [rtext], 'Reply Likes': [rlike]}
                    print(rauthor)
                    print(rtext)
            data = {'Comment':[comment],'Date':[comment2],'ID':[comment3], 'Likes':[comment4]}
            result = pd.DataFrame(data)
            result.to_csv('youtube.csv', mode='a',header=False)
            print(comment)
            print(comment2)
            print(comment3)
            print(comment4)
            print('==============================')
            comments.append(comment)
                
        # Check if another page exists
        if 'nextPageToken' in results:
            kwargs['pageToken'] = results['nextPageToken']
            results = service.commentThreads().list(**kwargs).execute()
        else:
            break

    return comments
```

When I do this, my crawler collects comments but doesn't collect some of the replies that are under certain comments.

How can I make it collect comments and their corresponding replies and put them in a single data frame?

### Update

So, somehow I managed to pull the information I wanted at the output section of Jupyter Notebook. All I have to do now is to append the result at the data frame.

Here is my updated code:

```
def get_video_comments(service, **kwargs):
    comments = []
    results = service.commentThreads().list(**kwargs).execute()

    while results:
        for item in results['items']:
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']
            comment2 = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['publishedAt']
            comment3 = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorDisplayName']
            comment4 = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['likeCount']
            if 'replies' in item.keys():
                for reply in item['replies']['comments']:
                    rauthor = reply['snippet']['authorDisplayName']
                    rtext = reply['snippet']['textDisplay']
                    rtime = reply['snippet']['publishedAt']
                    rlike = reply['snippet']['likeCount']
                    print(rtext)
                    print(rtime)
                    print(rauthor)
                    print('Likes: ', rlike)
                    
            print(comment)
            print(comment2)
            print(comment3)
            print("Likes: ", comment4)

            print('==============================')
            comments.append(comment)
                
        # Check if another page exists
        if 'nextPageToken' in results:
            kwargs['pageToken'] = results['nextPageToken']
            results = service.commentThreads().list(**kwargs).execute()
        else:
            break

    return comments
```

The result is:

[image: here]

As you can see, the comments grouped under `========` lines are the comment and corresponding replies underneath.

What would be a good way to append the result into the data frame?

Comment: It collects SOME replies, but not all. For example, if one comment has three replies, it won't add it to the CSV. What did I do wrong?!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can edit your questions, you don't have to add context in the comments.

Comment: @Aumazing_DaNub can you please mention what python youtube API wrapper are you using?

Comment: @Aumazing_DaNub also you're overwriting the `data` variable by `data = {'Reply ID':`..., not appending to it. You should learn how to append the comment results with your pandas DataFrame object (I would use pure python with list of dicts, not pandas, here).

Comment: @Timus Thanks! I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I am using YouTube Data API v3! The reason why I used Pandas was to turn the appended result to the CSV data frame easily. Since I am a super nub, idk if there is a better way of doing so. Based on the answer at the bottem, it seems like I might have to use different endpoint of API! Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 3):

According to the official doc, the property [`replies.comments[]`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#replies.comments%5B%5D) of [`CommentThreads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#resource-representation) resource has the following specification:

> [**replies.comments[]**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#replies.comments%5B%5D) (list)
> A list of one or more replies to the top-level comment. Each item in the list is a [comment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments#resource) resource.
>
> The list contains a limited number of replies, and unless the number of items in the list equals the value of the [`snippet.totalReplyCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#snippet.totalReplyCount) property, the list of replies is only a subset of the total number of replies available for the top-level comment. To retrieve all of the replies for the top-level comment, you need to call the [`Comments.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) method and use the [`parentId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#parentId) request parameter to identify the comment for which you want to retrieve replies.

Consequently, if wanting to obtain all reply entries associated to a given top-level comment, you will have to use the [`Comments.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) API endpoint queried appropriately.

I recommend you to read [my answer to a very much related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64031699/8327971); there are three sections:

- *Top-Level Comments and Associated Replies*,
- *The property `nextPageToken` and the parameter `pageToken`*, and
- *API Limitations Imposed by Design*.

From the get go, you'll have to acknowledge that the API (as currently implemented) does not allow to obtain all top-level comments associated to a given video when the number of those comments exceeds a certain (unspecified) upper bound.

---

For what concerns a Python implementation, I would suggest that you do structure the code as follows:

```
def get_video_comments(service, video_id):
    request = service.commentThreads().list(
        videoId = video_id,
        part = 'id,snippet,replies',
        maxResults = 100
    )
    comments = []

    while request:
        response = request.execute()

        for comment in response['items']:
            reply_count = comment['snippet'] \
                ['totalReplyCount']
            replies = comment.get('replies')
            if replies is not None and \
               reply_count != len(replies['comments']):
               replies['comments'] = get_comment_replies(
                   service, comment['id'])

            # 'comment' is a 'CommentThreads Resource' that has it's
            # 'replies.comments' an array of 'Comments Resource'

            # Do fill in the 'comments' data structure 
            # to be provided by this function:
            ...

        request = service.commentThreads().list_next(
            request, response)

    return comments
```

```
def get_comment_replies(service, comment_id):
    request = service.comments().list(
        parentId = comment_id,
        part = 'id,snippet',
        maxResults = 100
    )
    replies = []

    while request:
        response = request.execute()
        replies.extend(response['items'])
        request = service.comments().list_next(
            request, response)

    return replies
```

Note that the ellipsis dots above -- `...` -- would have to be replaced with actual code that fills in the array of structures to be returned by `get_video_comments` to its caller.

The simplest way (useful for quick testing) would be to have `...` replaced with `comments.append(comment)` and then the caller of `get_video_comments` to simply pretty print (using `json.dump`) the object obtained from that function.

Comment: Please ask for more details w.r.t. Python, if you feel needed.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! I will take a peek and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your rapid response! So if I try to use the Comment.list endpoint instead of CommentThread.list endpoint, do I have to write entirely new code? I know that I am a nub and suppose to learn more prior to doing these things. But I gotta make this thing quick due to some of the unavoidable circumstances :( I am wondering if you can help me understand the steps better! Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to drop using `CommentThread.list`, but have to use it in tandem with `Comments.list`. That is, for a given video, you'll iterate over all top-level comments (using pagination) by means of `CommentThread.list` and for each such top-level comment obtained, you'll iterate (again using pagination) over all its attached reply comments by means of `Comments.list`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on stvar' answer and the original publication [here](https://python.gotrained.com/youtube-api-extracting-comments) I built this code:

```
import os
import pickle
import csv
import json
import google.oauth2.credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json" # for more information  to create your credentials json please visit https://python.gotrained.com/youtube-api-extracting-comments/
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

def get_authenticated_service():
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            credentials = pickle.load(token)
    #  Check if the credentials are invalid or do not exist
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        # Check if the credentials have expired
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
            credentials = flow.run_console()

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(credentials, token)

    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def get_video_comments(service, **kwargs):
    request = service.commentThreads().list(**kwargs)
    comments = []

    while request:
        response = request.execute()

        for comment in response['items']:
            reply_count = comment['snippet'] \
                ['totalReplyCount']
            replies = comment.get('replies')
            if replies is not None and \
               reply_count != len(replies['comments']):
               replies['comments'] = get_comment_replies(
                   service, comment['id'])

            # 'comment' is a 'CommentThreads Resource' that has it's
            # 'replies.comments' an array of 'Comments Resource'

            # Do fill in the 'comments' data structure 
            # to be provided by this function:
            comments.append(comment)

        request = service.commentThreads().list_next(
            request, response)

    return comments
def get_comment_replies(service, comment_id):
    request = service.comments().list(
        parentId = comment_id,
        part = 'id,snippet',
        maxResults = 1000
    )
    replies = []

    while request:
        response = request.execute()
        replies.extend(response['items'])
        request = service.comments().list_next(
            request, response)

    return replies


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # When running locally, disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification. When
    # running in production *do not* leave this option enabled.
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
    service = get_authenticated_service()
    videoId = input('Enter Video id : ') # video id here (the video id of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vedLpKXzZqE -> is vedLpKXzZqE)
    comments = get_video_comments(service, videoId=videoId, part='id,snippet,replies', maxResults = 1000)


with open('youtube_comments', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in comments:
            # convert the tuple to a list and write to the output file
            writer.writerow([row])
```

it returns a file called **youtube_comments** with this format:

```
"{'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'gvhv4hkH0H2OqQAHQKxzfA-K_tA', 'id': 'UgzSgI1YEvwcuF4cPwN4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'tGTaBt4Hfd0', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'qpuKZcuD4FKf6BHgRlMunersEeU', 'id': 'UgzSgI1YEvwcuF4cPwN4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'tGTaBt4Hfd0', 'textDisplay': 'This is a comment', 'textOriginal': 'This is a comment', 'authorDisplayName': 'Gabriell Magana', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLRGBvo2ZncDP1xGjlX6anfUufNYi9b3w9kYZFDl=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKAa4FYftXsN7VKaPSlCivg', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCKAa4FYftXsN7VKaPSlCivg'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 8, 'publishedAt': '2019-05-22T12:38:34Z', 'updatedAt': '2019-05-22T12:38:34Z'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}"
"{'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'DsgDziMk7mB7xN4OoX7cmqlbDYE', 'id': 'UgytsI51LU6BWRmYtBB4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'tGTaBt4Hfd0', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'NYjvYM9W_umBafAfQkdg1P9apgg', 'id': 'UgytsI51LU6BWRmYtBB4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'tGTaBt4Hfd0', 'textDisplay': 'This is another comment', 'textOriginal': 'This is another comment', 'authorDisplayName': 'Mary Montes', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLTg1b1yw8BX8Af0PoTR_t5OOwP9Cfl9_qL-o1iikw=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_GP_8HxDPsqJjJ3Fju_UeA', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UC_GP_8HxDPsqJjJ3Fju_UeA'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 9, 'publishedAt': '2019-05-15T05:10:49Z', 'updatedAt': '2019-05-15T05:10:49Z'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 3, 'isPublic': True}, 'replies': {'comments': [{'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'Tu41ENCZYNJ2KBpYeYz4qgre0H8', 'id': 'UgytsI51LU6BWRmYtBB4AaABAg.8uwduw6ppF79DbfJ9zMKxM', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'tGTaBt4Hfd0', 'textDisplay': 'this is first reply', 'parentId': 'UgytsI51LU6BWRmYtBB4AaABAg', 'authorDisplayName': 'JULIO EMPRESARIO', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/eYP4MBcZ4bON_pHtdbtVsyWnsKbpNKye2wTPhgkffkMYk3ZbN0FL6Aa1o22YlFjn2RVUAkSQYw=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrpB9oZZZfmBv1aQsxrk66w', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCrpB9oZZZfmBv1aQsxrk66w'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 2, 'publishedAt': '2020-09-15T04:06:50Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-09-15T04:06:50Z'}}, {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'OrpbnJddwzlzwGArCgtuuBsYr94', 'id': 'UgytsI51LU6BWRmYtBB4AaABAg.8uwduw6ppF795E1w8RV1DJ', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'tGTaBt4Hfd0', 'textDisplay': 'the second replay', 'textOriginal': 'the second replay', 'parentId': 'UgytsI51LU6BWRmYtBB4AaABAg', 'authorDisplayName': 'Anatolio27 Diaz', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLR1hOySIxEkvRCySExHjo3T6zGBNkvuKpPkqA=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC04N8BM5aUwDJf-PNFxKI-g', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UC04N8BM5aUwDJf-PNFxKI-g'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 2, 'publishedAt': '2020-02-19T18:21:06Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-02-19T18:21:06Z'}}, {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'sPmIwerh3DTZshLiDVwOXn_fJx0', 'id': 'UgytsI51LU6BWRmYtBB4AaABAg.8uwduw6ppF78wwH6Aabh4y', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'tGTaBt4Hfd0', 'textDisplay': 'A third reply', 'textOriginal': 'A third reply', 'parentId': 'UgytsI51LU6BWRmYtBB4AaABAg', 'authorDisplayName': 'Voy detrás de mi pasión', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLTgzZ3ZFvkmmAlMzA77ApM-2uGFfvOBnzxegYEX=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvv6QMokO7KcJCDpK6qZg3Q', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCvv6QMokO7KcJCDpK6qZg3Q'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 2, 'publishedAt': '2019-07-03T18:45:34Z', 'updatedAt': '2019-07-03T18:45:34Z'}}]}}"
```

Now it is necessary a second step in order to information required. For this I a set of bash script toos like cut, awk and set:

```
cut -d ":" -f 10- youtube_comments | sed -e "s/', '/\n/g" -e "s/'//g" | awk '/replies/{print "------------------------****---------:::   Replies: "$6"  :::---------******--------------------------------"}!/replies/{print}' |sed '/^textOriginal:/,/^authorDisplayName:/{/^authorDisplayName/!d}' |sed '/^authorProfileImageUrl:\|^authorChannelUrl:\|^authorChannelId:\|^etag:\|^updatedAt:\|^parentId:\|^id:/d' |sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' | sed 's/{textDisplay/{\ntextDisplay/' |sed '/^snippet:/d' | awk -F":" '(NF==1){print "========================================COMMENT==========================================="}(NF>1){a=0; print $0}' | sed 's/textDisplay: //g' | sed 's/authorDisplayName/User/g' | sed 's/T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}Z//g' | sed 's/likeCount: /Likes:/g' | sed 's/publishedAt: //g' > output_file
```

The final result is a file called output_file with this format:

```
========================================COMMENT===========================================
This is a comment
User: Robert Everest
Likes:8, 2019-05-22
========================================COMMENT===========================================
This is another comment
User: Anna Davis
Likes:9, 2019-05-15
------------------------****---------:::   Replies: 3,  :::---------******--------------------------------
this is first reply
User: John Doe
Likes:2, 2020-09-15
the second replay
User: Caraqueno
Likes:2, 2020-02-19
A third reply
User: Rebeca
Likes:2, 2019-07-03
```

The python script requires of the file **token.pickle** to work, it is generated the first time the python script run and when it expired, it have to be deleted and generated again.

Comment: Since you have glossed over my answer below and, also, because you explicitly made use of GNU+Linux/Unix power tools, I recommend to check my tool: [Json-Type: JSON Push Parsing and Type Checking](https://www.nongnu.org/json-type/). Json-Type is able to very efficiently parse and type check JSON files/streams, and, also, very efficiently extract info from such sources. See the [README file](http://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/json-type.git/tree/README), specifically the subsection 4.g, *Extract (tabular) data from JSON input.*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that the OP does and managed to solve it, but someone in the community closed my question after I solved it and can't post there. I'm posting it here for fidelity.

The YouTube API doesn't allow users to grab nested replies to comments. What it does allow is you to get the replies to the comments and all the comments i.e. Video --> Comments --> Comment Replies ---> <s>Reply To Reply et al</s>. Knowing this limitation we can write code to get all the top Comments, and then break into those comments to get the first-level replies.

**Moduels**

```
import os
import googleapiclient.discovery #required for using googleapi
import pandas as pd #require for data munging. We use pd.json_normalize to create the tables
import numpy as np #just good to have
import json # the requests are returned as json objects. 
from datetime import datetime #good to have for date modification
```

**Get All Comments Function**
For a given vidId, this function will get the first 100 comments and place them into a df. It then use a while loop to check to see if the response api contains nextPageToken. While it does, it will continue to run to get all the comments until either all the comments are pulled or you run out of credits, whichever happens first.

```
def vidcomments(vidId):
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    DEVELOPER_KEY = "yourapikey" #<--- insert API key here

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)

    request = youtube.commentThreads().list(
        part="snippet, replies",
        order="time",
        maxResults=100,
        textFormat="plainText",
        videoId=vidId
    )
    
    response = request.execute()
    full = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['items'])
    while response:
        
        if 'nextPageToken' in response:
            response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
                part="snippet",
                maxResults=100,
                textFormat='plainText',
                order='time',
                videoId=vidId,
                pageToken=response['nextPageToken']
            ).execute()
            
            df2 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['items'])
            full = full.append(df2)
            
        else:
            break
    return full
```

**Get All Replies To Comments Function**
For a particular parentId, get all the first-level replies. Like the vidcomments() function noted above, it will run until all replies to all comments are pulled or you run out of credits, whichever happens first.

```
    def repliesto(parentId):
        # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
        # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
        os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

        api_service_name = "youtube"
        api_version = "v3"
        DEVELOPER_KEY = DevKey #your dev key

        youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)

        request = youtube.comments().list(
            part="snippet",
            maxResults=100,
            parentId=parentId,
            textFormat="plainText"
        )
        response = request.execute()

        replies = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['items'])
        while response:

            if 'nextPageToken' in response:
                response = youtube.comments().list(
                    part="snippet",
                    maxResults=100,
                    parentId=parentId,
                    textFormat="plainText",
                    pageToken=response['nextPageToken']                
                ).execute()

                df2 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['items'])
                replies = pd.concat([replies, df2], sort=False)

            else:
                break
        return replies
```

**Putting It Together**

First, run the vidcomments function to get all the comments information. Then use the code below to get all the reply information using a for loop to pull in each topLevelComment.id into a list, then use the list and another for loop to build the replies dataframe. This will create two separate Dataframes, one for Comments and another for Replies. After creating both of these Dataframes you can then join them in a way that makes sense for your purpose, either concat/union or a join/merge.

```
    replyto = []
    for reply in full[(full['snippet.totalReplyCount']>0)] 
    ['snippet.topLevelComment.id']:
        replyto.append(reply)

    # create an empty DF to store all the replies
    # use a for loop to place each item in our replyto list into the function defined above
    
    replies = pd.DataFrame()
    for reply in replyto:
        df = repliesto(reply)
        replies = pd.concat([replies, df], ignore_index=True)
```