# YouTube Data API how to extract more than 100 comments?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube Data API v3 to extract comments but the maximum I can get is 100 comments.

This is the code

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=1000&order=relevance&videoId=cosc1UEbMbY&key=MYKEY"

data = requests.get(url).json()

comments = []
co = 0;

for i in range(len(data['items'])):
  comments.append(data['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'])
```

Even if I set maxResults parameter to 1000, it only returns 100 comments.
How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: try looking for the nextPageToken in the JSON response, and use it in the next request

Comment: Here is answer to your question: [YouTube Data API to crawl all comments and replies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64276640/8327971). The code there fetches locally all comments (top-level and replies) of any given video using [Google's APIs Client Library for Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a key named "nextPageToken" in the JSON response, it can be used in the next request.

Heres a sample code snippet using the google-api-client for Python :

```py
if 'nextPageToken' in data:
    new_data = youtube.playlistItems().list(
    part='snippet',
    maxResults=100,
    pageToken=data['nextPageToken']
    )
    data= new_data.execute()
    # application code

else:
     pass
```