# Selenium Scraping Youtube Comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium to web scrape youtube comments. Because youtube uses a lot of javascript all of the comments won't be loaded so it has to scroll down and wait a couple of seconds and scroll again.

My current method to know when it should stop scrolling is to calculate how many scrolls it needs to do of how many comments the video has (Scroll goal). It works perfectly fine but even in the section "sort by new" all comments, won't be shown. So it actually only would need to scroll like 60%. Sure I can find a variable that fits better but...

Is there a better way to know when it has reached the end of the page?

```
for item in range(scrollGoal):   
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body"))).send_keys(Keys.END)
            time.sleep(10)
            print("Scroll:" + str(scrollCompleted))
            scrollCompleted += 1

        #Scrapes all the comments that has been rendered
for comment in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#author-thumbnail"))):
            print("Storing in List...")
            elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#author-thumbnail [href]")
            comment = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
            break
```

Comment: Not sure if you are required to use Selenium for this project but just a suggestion if you didn't know. There is a YouTube API which allows you to get the comments and if that's you're focus then it would be way better and eaiser to use that

Comment: See [one of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64276640/8327971) that provides Python code that fetches all comments (top-level and replies) of any given video using the Google's APIs Client Library for Python.