# YouTube Data API get all comments using pageToken

Tags: python, python-requests, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get all comments using pageToken.

This is my code

```
import requests 
import json 

link = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=100&videoId={videoId}&key={key}'

link_pageToken = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=100&pageToken={pageToken}&videoId={videoId}&key={key}'

key ='...'

videoId = 'ydDn_TFkzi4'

comments = []

data = requests.get(link.format(videoId = videoId, key = key)).json()

for i in range(len(data['items'])):
  comments.append(data['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'])

while 'nextPageToken' in data:
  data = requests.get(link_pageToken.format(videoId = videoId, key = key, pageToken = data['nextPageToken']))
  data = data.json()

  for i in range(len(data['items'])):
    comments.append(data['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'])
```

This code works fine but it's kinda redundant. So I tried to fix the code as below

```
import requests 
import json 

link_pageToken = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=100&pageToken={pageToken}&videoId={videoId}&key={key}'

key ='...'

videoId = 'ydDn_TFkzi4'

comments = []

data = requests.get(link_pageToken.format(videoId = videoId, key = key)).json()

while 'nextPageToken' in data:
  data = requests.get(link_pageToken.format(videoId = videoId, key = key, pageToken = data['nextPageToken']))
  data = data.json()

  for i in range(len(data['items'])):
    comments.append(data['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'])
```

However, code below raises `KeyError: 'pageToken'`.
My guess is that I first need to find out if there is pageToken and get pageToken, then insert it in the URL.

How can I do this?

Thank you

I tried furas's second answer. Here is the code

```
import requests 
import json 

link_pageToken = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=100&pageToken={pageToken}&videoId={videoId}&key={key}'

key ='...'

videoId = 'ydDn_TFkzi4'

comments = []

data = requests.get(link_pageToken.format(videoId = videoId, key = key, pageToken="")).json()

while 'nextPageToken' in data:
  data = requests.get(link_pageToken.format(videoId = videoId, key = key, pageToken = data['nextPageToken']))
  data = data.json()

  for i in range(len(data['items'])):
    comments.append(data['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'])
```

For some reason, compare to the very first code, it gathers less comments.
First code gathered 309 but this code gathers only 209 comments. Why is that?

Comment: always put full error message (stating at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful inforation.

Comment: in both `get()` you use the same `link_pageToken` but it expects `pageToken` which you don't have in first `format()` - and it can makes your problem. Try `"{pageToken}".format()
` and you get the same error. In first `get()` you should use old `link` or you should use `pageToken=""` in `format()`

Comment: Your code's third version gets only 209 items because you have two `requests.get` calls in a sequence (the one outside the `while` loop and the one inside that loop) and no `comments.append` in between. That is that your code does not retain the info contained in the first page (100 items) obtained from the first `request.get` call.

Comment: You may well see [one of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64276640/8327971) that provides Python code that fetches all comments (top-level and replies) of any given video using the [Google's APIs Client Library for Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

Comment: @stvar Thank you for the kind reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new version you use the same `link_pageToken`
in both `get()` but it expects `pageToken` which you don't have in first `format()`

Try `"{pageToken}".format()` and you get the same error.

---

In first `get()` you should use old `link` (without `{pageToken}`)

```
r = requests.get(link.format(videoId=videoId, key=key))
data = r.json()
```

or at least you should use `pageToken=""` in `format()`

```
r = requests.get(link_pageToken.format(videoId=videoId, key=key, pageToken=""))
data = r.json()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to use one link then you can do

```
link = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=100&pageToken={pageToken}&videoId={videoId}&key={key}'

r = requests.get(link.format(videoId=videoId, key=key)
data = r.json()
```

and later

```
link_pageToken = link + "&pageToken={pageToken}"

r = requests.get(link.format(videoId=videoId, key=key, pageToken=pageToken)
data = r.json()
```

OR use dictionary - it will be more readable

```
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads'

payload = {
     "part": "snippet",
     "maxResults": 100,
     "videoId": videoId,
     "key": key,
}

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
data = r.json()
```

and later add token

```
payload["pageToken"] = pageToken

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
data = r.json()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regarding first answer, I thought using two links are redundant, and that's why I tried to use just one link; link_pageToken. As you said, `first format()` does not have `pageToken` which causes the error. So I tried your second answer. It works but it's gathering less comments (309 to 209)

Comment: if this gives error then you have to use original `link` without `pageToken` because it seems even `pageToken=""` is treated as `token` and it is not correct token.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I have to use link and link_pageToken ?

Comment: yes - you should use old `link` in first `get()` and `link_pageToken` in second `get()`. But if you really need only one link then you should first use `link` and later `link + "&pageToken={pageToken}"`

Comment: by the way: in `requests` you can use also dictionary `{"part": "snippet", "maxResults": 100, "pageToken": ...}` with `get( ..., params=...)` and it will add them to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads` - and then you can first use dictionary without `pageToken` and later add `pageToken` to this dictionary.

Comment: I added example with dictionary.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for the detailed answer