# How do you get the comments of a video using the YouTube Java Client API when given the video ID?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am looking to write code that takes a video ID as input and retrieves the comments made on the corresponding video. Here's a [link to the API docs](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-youtube/latest/index.html). I tried this code

```
    String videoId = "id";
    YouTube.Comments.List list2 = youtube.comments().list(Arrays.asList("snippet"));
    list2.setId(Arrays.asList(videoId));
    list2.setKey(apiKey);
    Comment c = list2.execute().getItems().get(0);
```

but I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on the last line because `getItems` is returning an empty `List`. I set `videoId` as a valid YouTube video ID (one which I have already successfully been able to get video data like views, title, etc from), thinking that would work but clearly I was wrong. Unless I missed something I can't find anything in the docs for the `Video` class about getting comment data, so that's why I'm turning to SO for help again.

EDIT: Per stvar's comment I tried changing the second line of the above code to

```
YouTube.CommentThreads.List list2 = youtube.commentThreads().list(Arrays.asList("snippet"));
```

and of course changed the type of `c` to `CommentThread`.
It is the `CommentThreads` API I'm supposed to use, right? Either way, this is also returning an empty list...

Comment: You're not doing the right API call. Please read the [answer I provided to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64031699/8327971) that describes the APIs needed to be used for to retrieve all comments (top-level and replies) of a given video.

Comment: I edited the question with my 2nd attempt at trying to get the data after reading the answer you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete Java code that retrieves all comments (top-level and replies) of any given video:

```java
List<Comment> get_comment_replies(
    YouTube youtube, String apiKey, String commentId)
{
    YouTube.Comments.List request = youtube.comments()
        .list(Arrays.asList("id", "snippet"))
        .setParentId(commentId)
        .setMaxResults(100)
        .setKey(apiKey);
    List<Comment> replies = new ArrayList<Comment>();
    String pageToken = "";

    do {
        CommentListResponse response = request
            .setPageToken(pageToken)
            .execute();

        replies.addAll(response.getItems());

        pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
    } while (pageToken != null);

    return replies;
}

List<CommentThread> get_video_comments(
    YouTube youtube, String apiKey, String videoId)
{
    YouTube.CommentThreads.List request = youtube.commentThreads()
        .list(Arrays.asList("id", "snippet", "replies"))
        .setVideoId(videoId)
        .setMaxResults(100)
        .setKey(apiKey);
    List<CommentThread> comments = new ArrayList<CommentThread>();
    String pageToken = "";

    do {
        CommentThreadListResponse response = request
            .setPageToken(pageToken)
            .execute();

        for (CommentThread comment : respose.getItems()) {
            CommentThreadReplies replies = comment.getReplies();
            if (replies != null &&
                replies.getComments().size() !=
                comment.getSnippet().getTotalReplyCount())
                replies.setComments(get_comment_replies(
                    youtube, apiKey, comment.getId()));
        }

        comments.addAll(response.getItems());

        pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
    } while (pageToken != null);

    return comments;
}
```

You'll have to invoke `get_video_comments`, passing to it the ID of the video of your interest. The returned list contains all top-level comments of that video; each top-level comment has its `replies` property containing all the associated comment replies.